# filter select values base on first select id in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jquery code filter data base on given value of select, the problem is when I insert it to the database two field have pass same data the 'city' row and the 'brgy' couse they have same value given, is their a solution where the condition is not base on value given by select like id would be the condition. what area of jquery code should I modify?
*(note: I not good in jquery I also got this code in this platform.)*

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#city option").hide();
      $("#brgy option").hide();

      $("#region").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $("#city option").hide();
       $("#city").val("");
       $("#city option[value='" + val + "']").show();
       $("#city").change();
     });

     $("#city").change(function() {
       var val = $(this).find(":selected").prop("id");
       $("#brgy option").hide();
      $("#brgy").val("");
      $("#brgy option[value='" + val + "']").show();
     });

     });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select type="text" value="" id="region">
        <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
        <option value="" id="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
        <option value="" id="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
      </select>
    
      <select type="text" name="city" id="city">
        <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>
    
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
        <option value="" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
        <option value="" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
      </select>
    
      <select type="text" id="brgy">
        <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Baculin</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Batawan</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Batiano</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Binondo</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Campawan</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Central</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Lucod</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
        <option value="" id="Baganga">Mikit</option>
        <option value="" id="MatiCity">Central</option>
        <option value="" id="MatiCity">Badas</option>
        <option value="" id="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
        <option value="" id="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
      </select>
```

this is the working html using jQuery above

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <p>SELECT YOUR THE REGION
  <select type="text" value="" id="region">
    <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
      <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
      <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
     </select>
   </p><br><br>

  <p>SELECT YOUR THE CITY
     <select type="text" name="city" id="city">
       <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>

      <option value="DavaoOriental" id="Baganga">Baganga</option>
      <option value="CompostelaValey" id="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
        <option value="DavaoOriental" id="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
      </select>
    </p><br><br>

    <p>SELECT YOUR THE BARANGAY
      <select type="text" id="brgy">
        <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Baculin</option>
        <option value="Baganga">Batawan</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Batiano</option>
        <option value="Baganga">Binondo</option>
        <option value="Baganga">Bobonao</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Campawan</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Central</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Dapnan</option>
        <option value="Baganga">Kinablangan</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Lambajon</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Lucod</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Mahan-ub</option>
       <option value="Baganga">Mikit</option>
      <option value="MatiCity">Central</option>
       <option value="MatiCity">Badas</option>
       <option value="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
       <option value="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
    </select>
   </p><br><br>
```

problem is it save incorrect data to the database.

Comment: Please elaborate more .

Comment: in my current jQuery code work depend on options value but if i save it to my database there are field with same value because of jQuery condition base on value is there any way condition will be 'id' not the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use data-attributes to achieve this.So, in your html instead of giving same values to option you can use `data-any_name="value_in_common"` to your options and then in your jquery code you can use `$("#city [data-region='" + val + "']").show();` to show excepted options.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#city option").hide();
  $("#brgy option").hide();

  $("#region").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    $("#city option").hide();
    $("#city").val("");
    $("#city [data-region='" + val + "']").show(); //show options where attribute value matches.
    $("#city").change();
  });

  $("#city").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    $("#brgy option").hide();
    $("#brgy").val("");
    $("#brgy [data-city='" + val + "']").show();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="region">
  <option value="">Please Select Your Region</option>
  <option value="CompostelaValey">CompostelaValey</option>
  <option value="DavaoOriental">DavaoOriental</option>
</select>
<!--added data attribute-->
<select name="city" id="city">
  <option value="">Please Select City/Municipality</option>
  <option data-region="DavaoOriental" value="Baganga">Baganga</option>
  <option data-region="CompostelaValey" value="Maragusan">Maragusan</option>
  <option data-region="DavaoOriental" value="MatiCity">MatiCity</option>
</select>
<!--added data attribute-->
<select id="brgy">
  <option value="">Please Select Your Barangay</option>
  <option value="Baculin" data-city="Baganga">Baculin</option>
  <option value="Batawan" data-city="Baganga">Batawan</option>
  <option value="Binondo" data-city="Baganga">Binondo</option>
  <option value="Central" data-city="MatiCity">Central</option>
  <option value="Badas" data-city="MatiCity">Badas</option>
  <option value="Matiao" data-city="MatiCity">Matiao</option>
  <option value="kalapagan" data-city="Maragusan">kalapagan</option>
</select>
```